# What is the default font family in HTML and how can I check this?

Tags: html

For example follow simple HTML code display "Stack Overflow" in web browser. My question is what is the default font family and how can I check it? (Are there any specific way to check this?)

```
<body>
  Stack Overflow 
</body>
```

Comment: The default font family is whatever is specified by the user in the browser preferences.

Comment: Are there any method or way to get browser's font family? So can I change default font family in web browser according to my preference?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is an overview of default web browser fonts: http://www.granneman.com/webdev/coding/css/fonts-and-formatting/web-browser-font-defaults/

You can also download a browser plugin to select some text and get the font name (e.g Font Finder for Firefox)

Answer (score 4):

Each browser has a default stylesheet, e.g. this one from Chrome:

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/master/Source/core/css/html.css

Alternatively, just Inspect the element, and look at the computed tab.

Answer (score 0):

In browsers I use (Chrome, Opera, Firefox) default fonts are:
Standard font: Times New Roman,
Serif font: Times New Roman,
Sans-serif font: Arial,
Monospaced or fixed-width: Consolas (Firefox: Courier New).